# std::vector-like class optimized to hold a small number of items

Tags: c++, optimization, stl, micro-optimization

In one time-critical part of the program there is a member of the class that looks like that:
std::vector m_vLinks;
During profiling I noticed that about 99.98% of executions this vector holds only 0 or 1 items.
However in very rarely cases it might hold more.
This vector is definitely a bottleneck according to profiler, so I'm thinking about following optimization:

1. Craft a hand-made class with vector-like interface
2. This class will hold true size, one item and optional pointer to the vector
3. In this case when vector holds 1 item there won't be any dynamic memory allocations, and also accessing this item will be (a bit) faster due to removing of one indirection.
4. When we need to hold more data vector is dynamically allocated
5. Of course this vector won't provide one memory block holding all items (not needed here), and also some operations will be more complex

Before starting to prototype this thing to see if it helps, I wonder if anyone encountered custom containers with similar functionality in some 3rd-party libraries?

I already thought about boost::array, but don't want size limit that it imposes

Comment: Which operations exactly take most of the time in your scenario?

Comment: is vector a bottleneck because you frequently create new ones? In that case I doubt your optimization will help much...

Comment: Allocation and freeing vector's dynamic buffer (I use object pool to hold objects that have this member, but anyway need to periodically clean them by swapping vector of Links with empty vector, although this is not frequent operation).

Comment: http://llvm.org/docs/doxygen/html/classllvm_1_1SmallVector.html

Comment: did you try any compiler commands? there should be one for vectors that may help just sure the name

Comment: You could use a custom allocator to achieve this directly with `std::vector`. Check out Howard Hinnants `stack_alloc`: http://home.roadrunner.com/~hinnant/stack_alloc.html

Comment: So to be precise, the class usually holds 0 or 1 object, and should be optimized for that, but it *may* hold an unbounded number of objects?

Comment: Is there an upper bound on the number of objects? How many?

Comment: @phkahler: let's assume `std::vector<T>().max_size()` ;-)

Comment: @Fahrenheit2539: "This vector is definitely a bottleneck according to profiler" - doing *what* with the vector is definitely a bottleneck? If it's anything other than, "increasing its size from 0 to 1" or "copying it when its size is 1", then I don't see why your change would make a difference.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/36371057/1599699

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SDJImePyftY

Answer (score 9, accepted):

LLVM has a class for that called [SmallVector](http://llvm.org/docs/doxygen/html/classllvm_1_1SmallVector.html).

Comment: Of course, the one question: is it faster, really ? There is quite a heavy-weight hierarchy and I do wonder whether it can manage the speed of `vector` or not.

Comment: In general, hierarchies don't make code slow. Compilers see right through that. In particular, if you see stuff like `is_pod<T>` in a hierarchy, you know that's compile-time computing.

Comment: @MSalters: Sorry if it didn't sound right. What I meant is that there is way too much code for me to eyeball whether or not it will be faster than `vector`.

Comment: @MatthieuM. -- The following program runs in about 4.5 seconds for me: http://pastebin.com/Vmr47x0b -- When I switch it to use `llvm::SmallVector`, it goes to about 1.5 seconds.

Answer (score 8):

In a non-time-critical part of your code, perform: `m_vLinks.reserve(1);`. That way, in the time-critical part, there will typically be no dynamic allocation.

Comment: I like your proposition. Simple. Keep it simple. (+1)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/36371057/1599699

Answer (score 5):

My first attempt would be to optimize the memory allocator. Naive `malloc` implementations are not too efficient, you may want to try `tcmalloc` or `jemalloc`.

My second  attempt would be to change the allocator. Howard Hinnant has demonstrated how to use a stateful allocator that has some memory preallocated on the stack. This is only Standard compliant in C++11, but may already be supported.

My third attempt would be to change the code and pre-allocate the memory if possible. Instead of building the `vector` anew each time, you could keep it around: its capacity will not diminish and so subsequent uses won't allocate memory.

There are few chances that a homebrew implementation would match the speed of the `std::vector<T>` classes, as many of its methods have been tuned for maximum performance.

Answer (score 0):

I generally use `std::list` for these cases. The O(N) operations in `std::list` don't hurt me when N==1.

Comment: I suppose there is at least 1 dynamic memory allocation when item is added into the list (even if it is the first item). I needed the solution that could hold 1 item without any dynamic allocations

Comment: True, but that dynamic allocation is always the same size (single node), unlike std::vector, and the node pointer is always dereferenced. That's actually not as bad as you'd think, on modern hardware and with modern allocators.

Comment: The dynamic allocation is solved by the pool he's using. However, that leads to poor locality.