# std::vector capacity smart implementation

Tags: c++, vector, stdvector

I know that std::vector capacity behavior is implementation specific, is there any smart implementation that does this :

```
vector<int> v;
for(int i = 0; i < 10000 ; ++i){
    v.push_back(i);
}
```

At initialisation, it can predict the capacity of the 'vector', in this example it will initiate the capacity to `10000`

I am asking for this because I always thought gcc does this kind of predictions, but I couldn't find anything about this ... I think I have seen this somewhere, so is there any implementation that does this ?

Comment: There's nothing like that in any mainstream implementation, and it wouldn't *necessarily* be desirable in the general case, as normally if it throws `bad_alloc` during resize you end up with a partially populated `v`, while with your proposal you've have nothing at all.  Similar issues with more complex types that can throw during copying etc..

Comment: You should predict it manually... you can call a "reserve" to increase the capacity, so the vector won't copy the elems X times.

Comment: @Melkon I know I can predict it manually, but the compiler also can predict it staticly

Comment: @TonyD what resize ?

Comment: In this trivial case yes, it could predict, but in a real code you will probably never write something like this, so i guess it's not a priority for the compiler developers to optimize things like this.

Comment: @Melkon I know it wouldn't be possible in most cases, but in a case like this one, it would avoid many copies ... At least it could try, if it didn't predict it well, then it still can resize

Comment: I don't know, probably any kind of optimisation slows down compilation, maybe they just don't want to slow down compilation by trying to optimise things which is almost never happen. I think it's the programmers job to see how big the vector will be in a case like this. I don't know the exact reasons, but it's really a never happen case, you mostly iterate over containers and stuffs, in real world you don't know how much iteration you need 99,9% of times.

Comment: @Melkon you are probably right. It's just that I was pretty sure the compiler does this, and I still don't know why

Comment: @OthmanBenchekroun *"what resize?"* - if you `push_back` large numbers of elements without any prior `reserve()`, `vector` will `resize()` each time `size()` grows beyond `capacity()`. That behaviour has observable consequences, including in whether the allocations themselves might `throw`.  Any of these many behavioural differences precludes optimisation under the "as if" rule, meaning the Standard would need to explicitly grant permission for such an optimisation.  It doesn't.

Comment: If the compiler does what I asked for, it wouldn't need to resize. This is exactly the point of my question

Answer (score 3):

Nothing get predicted. However:

- one can use `reserve` to preallocate the maximum required amount of elements. `push_back` will then never need to reallocate.
- `push_back` use the growth strategy of `vector` that allocate more than just one mor element. IIRC the growth factor is 2, which means that the number of reallocation in a serie of `push_back` tends to become logarithmic. Therefore, the cost of N calls to `push_back` converges toward `log2(N)`.

Comment: The original growth factor of 2 was later described as a bad mistake causing memory overuse.

Comment: @curiousguy: by whom?  one person's memory overuse is another's poor performance... as a necessary compromise, 2 is at least in the right ballpark.

Comment: Asymptotically the cost of push_back is `log2` however that keeps into account unlimited memory. WIth limited memory (4 or 8 GB in example) you can grow by a minor factor and at same time save some memory without decreasing performance by too much. The perfect way is reserving the space in advance

Comment: @TonyD by those who count: committee members, implementers. 2 growth means that at worse you have 100% overhead in your vector.

Comment: @curiousguy: I'd be interested in the discussion - any links/references?  (Seems to me that if there was any kind of consensus amongst the "people who count" that 2 was not "good", it wouldn't be common in implementations - it's not actually specified in the Standard so can be changed freely by implementations at any time, as long as they don't pick a resizing scheme that invalidates the complexity requirements....)

Comment: @TonyD Growth factor was specified in the std in a very particular case. Other than that, most std STL implementations were at the time copies of SGI STL with few modifications.

Comment: FWIW, I remember (but cant find it) a blog post showing that x2 growth factor inhibit some modern OS into recycling memory efficiently as after N allocation of 1 2 4 .. 2^N bytes, then deallocating then allocating 2^N+1 can't fit into the free space of the 1 ... 2^N now deallocated memory block.

Answer (score -4):

It exists different constructor for std::vector. One of these possibilities is to say the default value and the number of values that you want to your vector.

From the documentation of [std::vector](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/vector/):

```
// constructors used in the same order as described above:
std::vector<int> first;                                // empty vector of ints
std::vector<int> second (4,100);                       // four ints with value 100
std::vector<int> third (second.begin(),second.end());  // iterating through second
std::vector<int> fourth (third);                       // a copy of third
```

This is useful if you know in advance the maximum size of your vector.

Comment: How is this an answer to my question ?

Comment: @OthmanBenchekroun You want to reserve the capacity of your vector in the moment that you instance it. You can do it like this: `std::vector<int> var(default_value,number_of_times);` . I understood that this was your question. I copied the different constructors of the stl documentation to give a wide idea of the differents possibilities.

Comment: @blashser that constructor does not reserve capacity only, it creates a vector with 4 ints ... Anyway, that is not even my question, I am looking for an implementation that can predict the vector's capacity

Comment: @OthmanBenchekroun Ok. Sorry, I understood wrongly. Until I know, it is not specified in any standard. There is at least a previous similar question `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12271017/initial-capacity-of-vector-in-c`

Comment: @blashser There is one standard, and I know it is implementation specific, that is why I am asking if anyone knows an implementation that does this

Comment: @OthmanBenchekroun what I don't get is how you come up with the idea, that something like *the compiler predicting* how much memory a vector is going to use can be implemented in the vector itself...You mean something like "compiler instructions/hints" in the implementation of the vector? Anyway, I must be misunderstanding your question, since this doesn't make any sense to me...

Comment: @dingalapadum you are understanding it well, I am not talking about the vector's implementation, but the way the compiler implements the vector's capacity, since it is implementation specified.