# vector() vs vector(0) unexplained runtime difference

Tags: c++, vector, stl

Version 1 (**1572.38ms**):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <chrono>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::steady_clock> startTime = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    int n = 1000000;
    int m = 1000;

    for (int k = 0; k < m; k++)
    {

        std::vector<int> array(0);

        array.reserve(n);

        for (int i = 0; i < n - 10; i++)
        {
            array.push_back(i);
        }
    }

    auto time = std::chrono::steady_clock::now() - startTime;
    std::cout   << "Elapsed time: "
            << std::chrono::duration<double, std::milli>(time).count()
            << " ms\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Version 2 (**3736.49ms**):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <chrono>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::steady_clock> startTime = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    int n = 1000000;
    int m = 1000;

    for (int k = 0; k < m; k++)
    {

        std::vector<int> array;

        array.reserve(n);

        for (int i = 0; i < n - 10; i++)
        {
            array.push_back(i);
        }
    }

    auto time = std::chrono::steady_clock::now() - startTime;
    std::cout   << "Elapsed time: "
            << std::chrono::duration<double, std::milli>(time).count()
            << " ms\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Can someone please explain to me why such a great difference in the running time? The only difference is in the vector construction. Both are created with size = capacity = 0.

Compiler: g++ 5.4.0
Compiler flags: -Wall -std=c++14 -O2

Comment: Did you compile with optimizations on?

Comment: What toolchain, platform, and build commands did you use?

Comment: Have you verified the loops haven't been optimized out entirely?

Comment: I updated the question with the compiler version/flags.
Even so, why would optimizations be different between these two sample codes? What is the difference between vector() and vector(0)?

Comment: "What is the difference between vector() and vector(0)?" - different ctor called

Comment: @Damjan http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector Slava is right, different constructors are indeed called.  See ctors 1 and 3

Comment: This seems very compiler specific. gcc 6.3 with -O3 compiles both examples to the same assembly, as does clang 3.9.1 with -O2.

Comment: Where do you start and stop timing? What exactly are you benchmarking? What methodology are you using? Either way, what you're seeing as a difference is almost certainly just noise. Current versions of both Clang and GCC emit *identical* code for these two snippets in optimized builds. Benchmarks only make sense if you run them *many* times and average the results.

Comment: Do note if you ever want to see the generated assembly you can always use [godbolt](http://gcc.godbolt.org/)

Comment: FWIW, libstdc++ tagged at 5.4 shows that the behavior of each constructor is identical (with `0`, it delegates to the default constructor then allocates via `_M_allocate`, which just short-circuits when `n == 0` to do nothing). You'll need to post your actual benchmarking; where does timing start, where does it stop, how many runs, etc. etc., just like Cody suggested.

Comment: "Both are created with size = capacity = 0"

Actually not.  Neither vector constructor specifies the capacity.

There's already a question about what the initial capacity actually is:
 http://stackoverflow.com/q/12271017/103167

Comment: I updated the question, it has the exact code I am compiling. The times have changed because I switched a computer, but the behavior is still unchanged.

Comment: Can you compare the assembly listings?

Comment: @GManNickG It's different very much, can't read assembly very well so not sure how to respond :/

Comment: Btw for you who say that your compiler produces exact assembly, it might be that everything is just optimized out? If that is the case, your test is missing the point - that vector() vs vector(0) causes 2x greater running time.

Comment: What *actually* misses the point is if you are benchmarking code with optimizations disabled. But no, the assembly listings I'm looking at do not have everything optimized out. The compiler is generating code, it's just generating identical code for virtually identical constructs, as you might expect. You can *consistently* get this difference, no matter how many time you run the benchmark? What about if you swap the order in which you do the tests (i.e., do Test 2 first, then Test 1)?

Comment: Yes, the results are consistent if I repeat the test and run it in any order.

Comment: Has anyone tested the code on the same compiler with the same flags and confirmed this?