# Is std::vector X(0) guaranteed not to allocate?

Tags: c++, vector, language-lawyer, allocation

In theory, given:

```
std::vector X(0);
```

Then X will allocate memory from the stack for itself, but is it guaranteed not to allocate heap memory?

In other words, since implementations will generally use a pointer for the vector, is this pointer always initially 0?

Note: this is not the same as [Initial capacity of vector in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12271017/initial-capacity-of-vector-in-c) since that asks about capacity when no argument is passed to the constructor, not about guarantees on heap allocations when capacity is 0;  The fact that capacity can be non-zero in this case illustrates the difference.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Initial capacity of vector in C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12271017/initial-capacity-of-vector-in-c)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That constructor calls `explicit vector( size_type count )` which does:

> Constructs the container with count default-inserted instances of T.
>   No copies are made.

The only guarantee you get is that the vector will be empty, its `size()` will be 0. Implementations are allowed to allocate whatever they want for book keeping or whatever on initialization.

So if your question is if you can count on `X` taking up 0 bytes of free store space then the answer is ***no***.

Comment: A notable exception I've had in practice is the Debug implementation of MSVC's Standard library (for debugging info I assume). We've had default constructed vectors in the implementation of objects that relied on an allocator that was set only later - before they were actually used, so it was safe in theory - but would fail to find the allocator directly on construction.