# What could generate memory leakage in this program

Tags: c++, c++11, memory-leaks

So I can't seem to find what does generate memory leakage in the next code.
My main looks like this

```
int main() {
    MovieRepo rep;
    _CrtDumpMemoryLeaks();
    return 0;
}
```

And MovieRepo class looks like this:

```
class MovieRepo{
protected:
    vector<Movie> all;
public:
    MovieRepo(){}
    ~MovieRepo(){}
}
```

And the Movie class looks like this:

```
class Movie {
    std::string title;
    std::string genre;
    std::string star;
    int year;

public:
    Movie(){}
    ~Movie(){}
}
```

The error I am getting from crtdbg:
Detected memory leaks!
Dumping objects ->
{152} normal block at 0x0094E710, 8 bytes long.
 Data: <  9     > DC FB 39 00 00 00 00 00 
Object dump complete.
Any idea?

Comment: Nothing in the code that you showed will leak memory.

Comment: Have you defined `_CRTDBG_MAP_ALLOC`?

Comment: @john C++ does not work this way, where all objects are deallocated inside of `main`.  That is where you placed that call to check for memory leaks.  What about global and static objects which get destructed outside of `main`?

Comment: Yes, #define _CRTDBG_MAP_ALLOC  #include <stdlib.h>  #include <crtdbg.h>

Comment: Is there anything else in your program that you're not showing? There won't even be any dynamic allocation with just the code you've shown.

Comment: Then I suppose it reports it as a leak because it is still allocated at the time of calling the `_CrtDumpMemoryLeaks` function. Try moving `MovieRepo` into a sub-scope.

Comment: @frederik , you were right, moving it between accolades solves it, thanks alot

Comment: @George no dynamic allocations? what about the `std::vector` and the `std::string`s?

Comment: @idclev463035818 Surely they won't dynamically allocate anything when constructed with 0 size?

Comment: @George initial capacity is not mandated by the standard. Typically it is 0, but it could be 2 or 42 as well

Comment: @George did some reasarch... point 1. here makes a good argument for no allocations on constucting the vector https://stackoverflow.com/a/59440860/4117728