# Small C++ container

Tags: c++, memory

Short story:  I need a container that can store an unlimited number of elements, but does no dynamic memory allocation for a small number of elements.

Long story: I need to store a couple of integers, the number of which is not bounded, but rarely more than two or three.  I tried using a `vector<int>` or `list<int>`, but the performance as compared to a simple array is worse by a factor of at least 50 in release mode, and 500 in debug mode.  For example, I measured creating a `vector`, calling `push_back` three times, and destroying it again. This takes around 250ns.  Calling `reserve(3)` upfront helps a bit, the time goes down to 100ns.  Using an array instead takes like 3ns, but I cannot use a fixed-size array because the number of elements is unbounded.  I need to store a lot of those things, as part of larger objects.

So I guess what I'm asking for is a container that uses some sort of small vector optimization: As long as the number of elements is small they are stored within the object itself, and only when it grows beyond a certain limit it allocates memory on the heap. Does such a thing exist?

As a side node, `basic_string` is known to have this sort of optimization, so I tried `basic_string<int>`.  Indeed, for a size of 3 it's four times faster than `vector<int>`, but somehow using a string class for storing integers doesn't feel right.  So again, my question:  Is there some container that performs well for small size, but if needed can grow unlimited?

**EDIT** People asked for the actual code.  Well, there is nothing special about it, it's straighforward.  I cannot post it because it's part of a large benchmarking environment, with special purpose classes for timing, and some classes for obfuscating the code to prevent the compiler from replacing it with `{}`.  You know, it does that when it notices the result isn't used.  The core of it comes down to this:

```
vector<int> v;
v.push_back(17);
v.push_back(19);
v.push_back(23);
```

and

```
int x[3];
int k = 0;
x[k++] = 17;
x[k++] = 19;
x[k++] = 23;
```

each of which is run in a tight timing loop.

**EDIT2** The use case for this is a tree with a variable number of branches at each node.  So I actually need to store pointers and no integers, but this is on 32-bit so both are the same size.  Performance of this is important, because the tree is constantly modified.

**Edit3** People keep doubting my numbers.  Why do you think they are unreasonable?  A `vector` does dynamic memory allocation, the array doesn't, and this seems to be a good explanation for the difference, or isn't it?

Comment: i'd allocate your average amount into a vector with `reserve`

Comment: Can you show code for the benchmark?

Comment: Something sounds fishy with your testing methodology.

Comment: @DanielA.White OP says that he tried that already.

Comment: You can assume `std::vector` is pretty well optimized already IMHO.

Comment: You cannot measure at 250 ns accuracy, let alone 3 ns. The numbers you’ve measured are completely random.

Comment: you should detail your use case, 100ns is likely to be a totally negligible overhead for  most applications. Besides, I'm curious: how could you benchmark with nanosecond precision? Real-time kernel? And did you take average and standard deviation over a significant number of runs? Was it a microbenchmark? Code profiling? Otherwise those figures are garbage...

Comment: @Joe  What do you mean, do you think the numbers are not reasonable?  Which number in particular?

Comment: "using a string class for storing integers doesn't feel right." What's wrong with it, apart from the name? There's a perfect solution for it, too: `typedef basic_string<int> small_container_for_ints;`

Comment: @Konrad Of course I did not measure running it once, but many times in a loop.  The loop overhead is just two machine instructions and less than 1ns.

Comment: Synthetic benchmarks aside, is this making any meaningful difference in actual production code?

Comment: @pentadecagon I’m not convinced. From experience, well over 95% of all microbenchmarks get it laughably wrong. And that’s not surprising, since microbenchmarks are *very easy* to get wrong. There are whole academic papers written about this subject. I wouldn’t trust any homebrew microbenchmark code. If you used a library, that’s something else of course, but it’s sufficiently rare here on SO that it’s worth mentioning in the question. But just running the benchmark in a code is most assuredly **not** enough.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Sure.  However, vector does dynamic memory allocation even for a very small size and that takes performance.

Comment: @pentadecagon and if you do `int* arr = new int[3];` its also dynamic memory allocation...

Comment: @VaughnCato  Adding code is difficult, I added some text as to why.  And why do you care?  Do you think the numbers are not plausible?

Comment: @pentadecagon: It would really help eliminate the debate over the quality if your test.

Comment: @StefanoSanfilippo  I added some text.  I need this for storing a tree.

Comment: @pentadecagon: A shot in the dark here, are you using VS2008 or less to compile? There is an issue where you may need to define _SECURE_SCL=0 in release mode to get better performance with STL.

Comment: @Konrad Do you think the numbers I posted are unreasonable?  They do make sense to me:  A `vector` need one or more dynamic memory allocations, and that eats time.  An array instead needs exactly no time for memory allocation.

Comment: @Vince  Thanks for the idea, but this isn't it.  I won't tell which compiler I'm using, because I think this issue is platform-independent.

Comment: Here is a program that demonstrates what he's talking about: https://ideone.com/cs4Dcm   You'll need to split it into the three files.  Having it all in one file makes it easier for the compiler to optimize away the array operations.

Comment: The version using std::basic_string<int> is actually much slower on my system.

Comment: Is the performance requirement for 2 or 3 elements the same as a gazillion elements? If not, use a fixed size array to cover 99% of the case and then string<void*> for the rest.

Comment: @pentadecagon Sorry, I got carried away over this. No, I think your numbers are entirely reasonable. Well, maybe I’m slightly wary of the huge fold change between the values but the trend is probably right. I also don’t think the question is a priori unreasonable – I’ve had similar problems situations in the past.

Comment: @ThomasMcLeod  That's exactly what I would like to do, but it's quite a lot of work with a number of possible pitfalls so I wanted to know if maybe such a thing exists already.

Comment: @VaughnCato Thanks for your effort.  Your string performance is interesting, but not really important, because I didn't consider this as a viable option anyway.  For the record, I used VS2013 for this.

Comment: This appears to be a dup: http://stackoverflow.com/q/9379204/951890

Comment: @VaughnCato  Indeed, it looks like a duplicate.  And I like the solution given there, I'll benchmark it and report back if it solves my problem.

Comment: The `Container` library of Boost v1.58 (april 2015) has the experimental [`small_vector`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/doc/html/container/non_standard_containers.html#container.non_standard_containers.small_vector) container.  Also take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/q/18530512/3235496